# What's the correct SELinux type for a directory?

Tags: linux, selinux

If I create a new filesystem/directory off of / and I set the Linux permissions to 770 I expect the group to be able to read and write files in that directory. SELinux was preventing me from doing this until I changed the SELinux type on that directory to public_content_rw_t. If this is just a directory in which users in that group will share files is this an acceptable SELinux type or should I be using another one? Writing a custom policy seems like overkill for these purposes.

Thanks

Comment: It will depend on what you plan to do in that directory. But in most cases, yes public_content_rw_t is fine.

Comment: Share files with what program? `public_content_rw_t` might be too much since it's for all programs, while for example `samba_share_t` is just for samba.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -lZ dirname
```

or

```
ls -l
```

but look at the 10th location on the directory line. If there is a "+" after the 3 rwx triplets, then there is an acl associated with the directory at the minimum.  A chmod will
remove the acl though. See also getfacl,setfacl, etc.

Comment: chmod won't always remove *all* ACLs associated with a file - If the `+` persists after a chmod you must use `setfacl` to clear the ACL entries.